# RAD FileNotFoundException Access is denied to C:\Users\abc\IBM\rationalsdp\workspace\some_project\bin

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, apache-axis, filenotfoundexception, ibm-rad

If I export the EAR and deploy it through the admin console, everything works fine.

However, when I "Add/remove project" from within the IDE, I keep getting `NoClassDefFoundError` due to `Axis2Utils java.io.FileNotFoundException C:\Users\abc\IBM\rationalsdp\workspace\someproject\bin (Access is denied)`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Turn out, this is a RAD problem on upgrading the JDK. I had to add the wsldLocation attribute to the web service implementation class.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21667356